# "The default measuring unit is inch" vs "The default measuring units are inches"

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct way to say that I will take measurements in inches?

1. The default measuring unit is "inch"

OR

2. The default measuring units are inches

OR

3. Other expressions?

Comment: "The default measuring unit is the inch."

Comment: Why measuring? Would "default measurement unit is inches" work?

Comment: I would say *the default measuring* ***unit is*** *inches*. It doesn't matter what follows *is*. *The unit is (whatever).*

Comment: @JasonBassford After giving it more thought, I believe you're definitely right.